# Since nested views are seen as taboo - how else should I go about constructing an extremely verbose query?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, database-administration

Background: A webdev did not take SQL seriously enough back in college and is now regretting it while working for a financial company using Snowflake as a data warehouse to compute statistics.

### We have 3 source tables that are used for all calculations:

- **Positions:**

```
create or replace TABLE POS (
    ACCOUNT_NUMBER VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    ACCOUNT_TYPE VARCHAR(30),
    SECURITY_TYPE VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    SYMBOL VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    QUANTITY NUMBER(15,4),
    AMOUNT NUMBER(15,4),
    FILE_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    primary key (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, SYMBOL, FILE_DATE)
);
```

- **Transactions:**

```
create or replace TABLE TRN (
    REP_CODE VARCHAR(10),
    FILE_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    ACCOUNT_NUMBER VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    CODE VARCHAR(10),
    CANCEL_STATUS_FLAG VARCHAR(1),
    SYMBOL VARCHAR(100),
    SECURITY_CODE VARCHAR(2),
    TRADE_DATE DATE,
    QUANTITY NUMBER(15,4),
    NET_AMOUNT NUMBER(15,4),
    PRINCIPAL NUMBER(15,4),
    BROKER_FEES NUMBER(15,4),
    OTHER_FEES NUMBER(15,4),
    SETTLE_DATE DATE,
    FROM_TO_ACCOUNT VARCHAR(30),
    ACCOUNT_TYPE VARCHAR(30),
    ACCRUED_INTEREST NUMBER(15,4),
    CLOSING_ACCOUNT_METHOD VARCHAR(30),
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(500)
);
```

- **Prices:**

```
create or replace TABLE PRI (
    SYMBOL VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    SECURITY_TYPE VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    FILE_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    PRICE NUMBER(15,4) NOT NULL,
    FACTOR NUMBER(15,10),
    primary key (SYMBOL, FILE_DATE)
);
```

These tables on their own are all effectively useless and messy, they almost always need to be joined with one another (or themselves) and have many additional calculations applied to them to be interpreted in any meaningful way. Views have helped me encapsulate this issue.

There are two core views that I use downstream from these tables:

1. **Holdings**

```
SELECT 
    POS.FILE_DATE, 
    POS.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, 
    POS.SYMBOL,
    CASE WHEN POS.QUANTITY > 0 THEN POS.QUANTITY ELSE POS.AMOUNT END AS QUANTITY,
    CASE WHEN POS.SECURITY_TYPE IN ('FI', 'MB', 'UI') THEN
        COALESCE(
            PRI.FACTOR * PRI.PRICE * .01,
            PRI.PRICE * .01
        )
        ELSE PRI.PRICE END AS PPU,
    COALESCE(
        POS.AMOUNT,
        QUANTITY * PPU
    ) AS MARKET_VALUE
FROM POS AS POS 
LEFT JOIN PRI AS PRI 
    ON POS.FILE_DATE = PRI.FILE_DATE AND POS.SYMBOL = PRI.SYMBOL;
```

2. **Cashflows** (this one a is a doozy... our data provider really doesn't help much here)

```
select t.file_date, T.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
    COALESCE (
        CASE WHEN T.SECURITY_CODE = 'MB' THEN INIT * p.factor * .01 ELSE NULL END, -- IF Factor and Par needed
        CASE WHEN T.SECURITY_CODE IN ('FI', 'UI') THEN INIT * .01 ELSE NULL END, -- if par val needed
        CASE WHEN T.QUANTITY > 0 AND P.PRICE > 0 THEN t.quantity * p.price ELSE NULL END,
        CASE WHEN T.NET_AMOUNT > 0 and p.price is not null THEN T.NET_AMOUNT * p.price ELSE NULL END,
        T.NET_AMOUNT, -- if the transaction has a net value
        BUYS.NET_AMOUNT, -- if there is a buy aggregate match for the day
        SELLS.NET_AMOUNT -- if there is a sell aggregate match for the day
    ) AS DERIVED, -- this records the initial cash flow value
    COALESCE( 
        CASE WHEN t.code IN ('DEP', 'REC') THEN DERIVED ELSE NULL END,
        CASE WHEN t.code IN ('WITH', 'DEL', 'FRTAX', 'EXABP') THEN -1 * DERIVED ELSE NULL END
    ) as DIRECTION, -- this determines if it was an inflow or outflow
    CASE 
        WHEN T.CANCEL_STATUS_FLAG = 'Y' THEN -1*DIRECTION 
        ELSE DIRECTION 
    END AS FLOW, -- this cancels out an existing transaction
    CASE WHEN T.CODE = 'MFEE' THEN INIT ELSE NULL END AS FEES,
    t.code, 
    t.symbol, 
    t.net_amount, 
    t.quantity, 
    p.price,
    p.factor
from trn t
LEFT JOIN PRI p 
    ON t.symbol = p.symbol 
    AND t.file_date = p.file_date
-- in the rare case that we dont have a securities price, it means that a buy/sell 
-- transaction occurred to remove the position from our 
-- data feed. This must mean that the transaction value 
-- is equivalent to the total internal operation that occurred to a particular security in 
-- this account on this day.
LEFT JOIN (
    select file_date, 
        account_number, 
        symbol, 
        SUM(net_amount) as net_amount 
    from TRN 
    where code = 'BUY' 
    group by file_date, account_number, symbol
) AS buys 
    ON t.code = 'DEL'   
    AND buys.file_date = t.file_date  
    AND buys.symbol = t.symbol  
    AND buys.account_number = t.account_number
    AND p.price IS NULL
    AND t.net_amount = 0
    AND buys.net_amount != 0
LEFT JOIN (
    select file_date, 
        account_number, 
        symbol, 
        SUM(net_amount) as net_amount 
    from TRN 
    where code = 'SELL' 
    group by file_date, account_number, symbol
) AS sells 
    ON t.code = 'REC' 
    AND t.file_date = sells.file_date 
    AND sells.symbol = t.symbol 
    AND sells.account_number = t.account_number
    AND p.price IS NULL
    AND t.net_amount = 0
    AND sells.net_amount != 0
WHERE 
    t.code in ('DEP', 'WITH', 'DEL', 'REC', 'FRTAX', 'MFEE', 'EXABP')
ORDER BY t.file_date;
```

I also wrote views to group the two views above by their account number, named **account_balances** and **grouped_cashflows**, respectively. I call these two views often from my application layer, and have been satisfied with the execution speed thus far.

### With all of that out of the way....

I am now attempting to compute the **time weighted performance** of each investment account. Id prefer to do this using SQL instead of in the application layer so that I can view the output in those *sweet sweet* Snowflake Dashboards.

The formula I am using is known as [TWRR](https://www.canadianportfoliomanagerblog.com/how-to-calculate-your-time-weighted-rate-of-return-twrr/).

In summary, it requires me to gather all historical balances + all cash flows, compute the net difference between each consecutive set of market closes, and record it as a percentage. If we then denote this percentage + 1 as "factor", and take the product of all these factors over a given time frame and subtract 1, we have the performance for that timeframe.

So... my first try, I did exactly what you'd expect - created a another view called factors, which referenced my other views:

```
SELECT 
B.FILE_DATE, 
B.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, 
B.MARKET_VALUE AS EMV,
COALESCE(CF.FLOW, 0) AS NET,
COALESCE(CF.FEES, 0) AS FEES,
COALESCE(NET + FEES, NET, 0) AS GRS,
LAG(B.MARKET_VALUE, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY B.ACCOUNT_NUMBER ORDER BY B.FILE_DATE) AS LAST_BAL,
COALESCE( 
    LAST_BAL, 
    B.MARKET_VALUE - NET,
    B.MARKET_VALUE
) AS BMV,
EMV - BMV AS DIFF,
DIFF - NET AS NET_DIFF,
DIFF - GRS AS GRS_DIFF,
CASE WHEN BMV > 10 AND EMV > 10 AND NET_DIFF / BMV < 1 AND GRS != 0 THEN 1 + (NET_DIFF / BMV) ELSE 1 END AS NET_FACTOR,
CASE WHEN BMV > 10 AND EMV > 10 AND GRS_DIFF / BMV < 1 AND GRS != 0 THEN 1 + (GRS_DIFF / BMV) ELSE 1 END AS GRS_FACTOR
FROM ACCOUNT_BALANCES B 
LEFT JOIN GROUPED_CASHFLOWS CF 
    ON B.FILE_DATE = CF.FILE_DATE 
    AND B.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = CF.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
order by ACCOUNT_NUMBER, FILE_DATE;
```

This query works, however, as you can guess, it is *really... really... **slow**.*  Like, 10 seconds for certain accounts (admittedly, using an xs snowflake instance, but still.)

At this point, it was clear that I was doing something wrong, and sure enough, a quick google search made it abundantly clear that it is a huge no-no to nest views like this.

The thing is though... writing all of this out as a single query without using my views just seems... horrible.

So to all you SQL/Snowflake gurus out there... Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Any advice at all would be very appreciated.

Edit: Including the snowflake query profile for the factors view:

[image]

**Thank you!**

Comment: Have you used the query profile tool? Are you running out of memory? Why is Holdings 'select' instead of 'create materialized view Holdings as select'?  You know that subqueries optimize differently than views? I haven't written an answer because I'm not a snowflake user, but those are obvious areas for consideration.

Comment: view are only bad if the filtering you want are not pushed down. If you write it as one large block, or with CTE and still don't push the filters down, you will have the same performance.

Comment: you can also use User Defined Table Functions, to pass parameters like filters, thus force the filtering to be pushed down, we did that for a number of security layers. But if you are reading the data for all time, there is nothing bad about view/cte's. Yes, materializing the view or make temp tables might be more performant. But it can also not be more performant (due to remote IO)

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim This is exactly what my intuition was telling me, I just didn't have a way to put that in words. How does one exactly 'push down' a filter?

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim whoops, asked and answered at the same time. Looking into this now. Thank you!

Comment: the hint that filtering is not getting push down enough, is when in the query-profile, there is large number of row being pasted through many expensive layers and then being dropped by a filter, and the logic of the filter could have applied before the expensive steps.

Comment: But sometime the data is changed enough that how to filter is not clear, so if for example you want only the result of the last month, but in a sub-layer there is a LAG, it is going to reach indefinitly back, but if you know you have always some data each week, in the UDTF to can use a passed in start_time and then step back 1-2 weeks and thus chop out years of table scan that are not needed.

Comment: @david I've included an image of my query profile to my post.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim I see. I've included an image of the query profile to my post - I believe I see exactly what you mean by this occurring on the table scan of POS and TRN.

Comment: look at that profile it does not appear to be filter push down failure. You only have 1K rows tops.. unless that is of a incomplete run?

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim That is a complete run. You're right - it does appear to be filtering properly across the nested views. How is that possible? Shouldn't the nested views not take the filter on the factors table into consideration? Does Snowflake employ some kind of magic here?

Comment: view are just "blocks of pre-written sql" thus filters can/do get pushed down. But sometime the complexity of a view means an impactful filter is not pushed down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far I only see tiny things that I don't think will stack up to anything large.

From holdings:

```
    CASE WHEN POS.SECURITY_TYPE IN ('FI', 'MB', 'UI') THEN
        COALESCE(
            PRI.FACTOR * PRI.PRICE * .01,
            PRI.PRICE * .01
        )
        ELSE PRI.PRICE END AS PPU,
```

the a two legged CASE in snowflake is the same as using IFF and IFF is a little easier to read, imho. And the math can be tweaked.

```
    IFF(POS.SECURITY_TYPE IN ('FI', 'MB', 'UI'),
        PRI.PRICE * .01 * COALESCE(PRI.FACTOR, 1),
        PRI.PRICE) AS PPU,
```

is cashflow, the large COALESCE for derived, could become a CASE statement, but perhaps that would not be faster:

thus:

```
    COALESCE (
        IFF( T.SECURITY_CODE = 'MB', INIT * p.factor * .01, NULL), -- IF Factor and Par needed
        IFF( T.SECURITY_CODE IN ('FI', 'UI'), INIT * .01, NULL), -- if par val needed
        IFF( T.QUANTITY > 0 AND P.PRICE > 0, t.quantity * p.price, NULL),
        IFF( T.NET_AMOUNT > 0 and p.price is not null, T.NET_AMOUNT * p.price, NULL),
        T.NET_AMOUNT, -- if the transaction has a net value
        BUYS.NET_AMOUNT, -- if there is a buy aggregate match for the day
        SELLS.NET_AMOUNT -- if there is a sell aggregate match for the day
    ) AS DERIVED, -- this records the initial cash flow value
```

could be

```
    CASE 
        WHEN T.SECURITY_CODE = 'MB' THEN INIT * p.factor * .01
        WHEN T.SECURITY_CODE IN ('FI', 'UI') THEN INIT * .01
        WHEN T.QUANTITY > 0 AND P.PRICE > 0 THEN t.quantity * p.price
        WHEN T.NET_AMOUNT > 0 and p.price is not null THEN T.NET_AMOUNT * p.price
        ELSE COALESCE(
            T.NET_AMOUNT, -- if the transaction has a net value
            BUYS.NET_AMOUNT, -- if there is a buy aggregate match for the day
            SELLS.NET_AMOUNT -- if there is a sell aggregate match for the day
        ) 
    END AS DERIVED, -- this records the initial cash flow value
```

Hmm this might be somethings.

In cashflow, you make `buys` and `sells` and you only left join those aggregations, if the `t.net_amount = 0` BUT only use those values in:

```
        ELSE COALESCE(
            T.NET_AMOUNT, -- if the transaction has a net value
            BUYS.NET_AMOUNT, -- if there is a buy aggregate match for the day
            SELLS.NET_AMOUNT -- if there is a sell aggregate match for the day
        )
```

COALESCE will only use those values if `t.net_amount` is null. But those values will only be present if `t.net_amount` is zero so `buys` and `sells` is 100% wasted compute. So ether the join should be `t.net_amount is null` or those can be dropped.

Then there is things like

```
CASE WHEN T.CODE = 'MFEE' THEN INIT ELSE NULL END AS FEES
```

and later that is coalesced to zero if null, (which might handle the left joins also). but it could just be zero here. But also it points that `T.CODE` can equal 'MFEE' and DIRECTION does not handle this, so direction can be null, thus FLOW can be null.

Comment: Wow - thank you so much for the detailed analysis. I really appreciate it. Every single one of the bugs you mention went right over my head, I've fixed them after you pointed them out. That said, I am still curious as to why this query is taking so long to execute... We are using a trial instance of snowflake at the moment, (purchasing as soon as it expires), but even with the xsmall instance, 5-10 seconds to process at maximum 1.4k records seems a tad excessive... Are there any other things I could look into to speed things up?

Comment: Without the exact data and exact full SQL, its hard to say as I am not seeing obvious problems.

Comment: Yeah, fair enough. Well thank you anyway! I'm sure it's probably just the warehouse, perhaps I've exhausted my credit balance. Either way - awarding you. Really appreciate your thoroughness.

Answer (score 1):

@SimeonPilgrim provided an amazing analysis, along with helpful tips, so I'm not going to add anything there.

However, one red flag popped out to me when you said:

> This query works, however, as you can guess, it is really... really... ***slow***. Like, 10 seconds for certain accounts.

This is the wrong way to use Snowflake (or a data warehouse in general):

- Data warehouses are [OLAP systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing), which are designed to handle large analytical queries (not small transactional queries). You will not obtain sub-second query results from an OLAP system (and usually, just about any query will take at least a few seconds).

  - **In general, OLAP performance is measured in seconds (if not minutes & hours).**
- In contrast, application databases (like MySQL & PostgreSQL) are [OLTP systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_transaction_processing), which are designed to handle a large number of small transactional queries very quickly (for application performance).

  - **In general, OLTP performance is measured in milliseconds.**

The red flag is this: "10 seconds for certain accounts", which makes it sound like you are processing accounts *one by one*. Instead, you should run your query for all accounts (or a subset/group of accounts), and then process the results per account in an external system (be it a spreadsheet, or a programming environment).

---

If you want to put this information in a dashboard, you should consider using a BI tool instead:

- There are some open-source ones, like [Metabase](https://www.metabase.com/), which are "free" if self-hosted.
- But most of them will simply run queries against Snowflake anyway; so the result would be the same as those Snowflake dashboards you mentioned.
- However, some of them (like [Tableau](https://www.tableau.com/)), allow you to locally extract the data from Snowflake in order to refresh dashboards faster.

  - The idea then would be to extract all your per-account data to Tableau (i.e. the entirety of that final time weighted performance view), and use a filter to specify which account to display.
  - Tableau isn't cheap though, so if that doesn't work for you, Excel/Google Sheets is probably your best bet. You can use a specific cell to specify which account to display in the charts -- you could even make it a dropdown of possible values.

---

P.S. Nested views are not really taboo nowadays. In fact, analytics engineers make extensive use of them (via tools like [DBT](https://www.getdbt.com/)).

Comment: These are some very valid points, nicely framed.